# Get Error:device or resource busy when capturing video using v4l2 driver

Tags: c, vlc, v4l2

I already have a kernel driver `vcam` which already implement all file operation needed by v4l2 (this driver is guaranteed correct), and it will create `video1` under `/dev`.

I can use `vlc` to open video

```
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video1
```

Also, I can write random data into `vcam`'s frame buffer. Then, random pixel will show up in window which I opened through `vlc`

```
$ cat /dev/urandom > /proc/vcamfb1       # write random signal
```

I tried to write a user application to capture value in `video1`, code is basically like example [here](https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534).

Everytime when I tried set format or request buffer through `ioctl`, I will get error message:

```
VIDIOC_REQBUFS error 16, Device or resource busy\n
```

I know the thing what I did is meaningless but the reason for me to do so is trying to be familiar with v4l2. It seems like not allow me to capture the video which is writing.

My question are:

1) What wrong with my concept about **capturing**, can you give me some scenario about why we need feature of v4l2 capturing ?

2) What is the usage for [link](https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534) mentioned above, I need some scenario.